# iOS - Showing App version in HTML page

Tags: html, ios, version

I'm showing About in form of html in my iOS application. About.html is also bundled along with the application.
I want to show the application version in About html page automatically so that I dont have to edit the HTML manually everytime I bump the version.
Currently what I'm doing is as below:
I'm creating the html as `<b>Version %@</b>` 
In Objective C code, I'm writing it as

```
    NSString* aboutFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlStr = [NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aboutFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString* formattedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlStr, [self appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString];
   [self.webView loadHTMLString:formattedStr baseURL:nil];

- (NSString *)appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *appDisplayName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
    NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *minorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Version %@ (%@)", 
                appDisplayName, majorVersion, minorVersion];
}
```

Is it good way to do it or is there any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in near to perfect manner. There is no problem in proceeding with your approach.

Comment: I dont need any server that my app has to connect. But my question is related to showing automatic version number.

Answer (score 0):

That's ok. If you want to localise the text in the future then that might change the order of the parameters in the text so using something more like `SUB_VERSION` as the identifier to be replaced and then using the string replacement methods (instead of format method) would be better.